# Weird MVC Model behavior in EditorTemplate

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How is it possible that in a razor EditorTemplate the following commands generate a different value for the same ViewModel:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Value)
@Model.Value
```

And no, in the Value get property, the value is not changed

Update 1:
Sorry guys for the short message, you know, tired, frustrated...
Made a sample, got rid of all the partials and templates.
Give the textbox number 1, hit add, number 2, hit add, number 3, hit add.
The remove number 2.
The result is an out of sync between the textbox and the displayed value.

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        TestModel testModel = TestModel.Create();
        Session["model"] = testModel;
        return View("Index", testModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Submit(TestModel submitModel, string submit)
    {
        // merge values in current form
        var testModel = Session["model"] as TestModel;
        if (testModel == null) throw new Exception("No current model found.");
        testModel.MergeFieldValues(submitModel);

        if (submit.StartsWith("Add_"))
        {
            var rowGroupId = Guid.Parse(submit.Substring("Add_".Length));
            TestRowGroup rowGroup = testModel.Groups.SelectMany(g => g.RowGroups).Single(rg => rg.RowGroupId == rowGroupId);
            rowGroup.AddFieldRow();
        }
        if (submit.StartsWith("Del_"))
        {
            var fieldRowId = Guid.Parse(submit.Substring("Del_".Length));
            testModel.RemoveFieldRow(fieldRowId);
        }
        return View("Index", testModel);
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public List<TestGroup> Groups { get; set; }

    public static TestModel Create()
    {
        var testModel = new TestModel { Groups = new List<TestGroup>() };
        var grp = new TestGroup { RowGroups = new List<TestRowGroup>() };
        var rowGrp = new TestRowGroup { RowGroupId = Guid.NewGuid(), FieldRows = new List<TestFieldRow>() };
        var fldRow = new TestFieldRow { FieldRowId = Guid.NewGuid(), Fields = new List<TestFormField>() };
        var fld = new TestFormField { FieldId = Guid.NewGuid() };
        fldRow.Fields.Add(fld);
        rowGrp.FieldRows.Add(fldRow);
        grp.RowGroups.Add(rowGrp);
        testModel.Groups.Add(grp);
        return testModel;
    }

    public void MergeFieldValues(TestModel src)
    {
        foreach (var srcField in src.Groups.SelectMany(g => g.RowGroups.SelectMany(rg => rg.FieldRows.SelectMany(fr => fr.Fields))))
        {
            var destField = Groups.SelectMany(g => g.RowGroups.SelectMany(rg => rg.FieldRows.SelectMany(fr => fr.Fields))).FirstOrDefault(f => f.FieldId == srcField.FieldId);
            if (destField == null) throw new Exception("Field not found during merge");
            destField.Value = srcField.Value;
        }
    }

    public void RemoveFieldRow(Guid fieldRowId)
    {
        foreach (var group in Groups)
        {
            foreach (var rowGroup in group.RowGroups)
            {
                rowGroup.FieldRows.RemoveAll(fieldRow => fieldRow.FieldRowId == fieldRowId);
            }
        }
    }   
}

public class TestGroup
{
    public List<TestRowGroup> RowGroups { get; set; }
}

public class TestRowGroup
{
    public List<TestFieldRow> FieldRows { get; set; }
    public Guid RowGroupId { get; set; }

    public void AddFieldRow()
    {
        var newRow = new TestFieldRow
        {
            Fields = new List<TestFormField>()
        };
        newRow.FieldRowId = Guid.NewGuid();
        var fld = new TestFormField { FieldId = Guid.NewGuid() };
        newRow.Fields.Add(fld);
        FieldRows.Add(newRow);
    }
}

public class TestFieldRow
{
    public Guid FieldRowId { get; set; }
    public List<TestFormField> Fields { get; set; }                
}

public class TestFormField
{
    public Guid FieldId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model FieldTest.Models.TestModel

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        for (int g = 0; g < Model.Groups.Count; g++)
        {
            for (int rg = 0; rg < Model.Groups[g].RowGroups.Count; rg++)
            {
                for (int fr = 0; fr < Model.Groups[g].RowGroups[rg].FieldRows.Count; fr++)
                {
                    for (int f = 0; f < Model.Groups[g].RowGroups[rg].FieldRows[fr].Fields.Count; f++)
                    {
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Groups[g].RowGroups[rg].FieldRows[fr].Fields[f].FieldId)

                        @Model.Groups[g].RowGroups[rg].FieldRows[fr].Fields[f].Value
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Groups[g].RowGroups[rg].FieldRows[fr].Fields[f].Value)

                        <button onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you would like to remove this row?');" type="submit" value="@string.Format("Del_{0}", Model.Groups[g].RowGroups[rg].FieldRows[fr].FieldRowId)" name="submit">Remove</button>
                        <hr />
                    }
                }
                <button type="submit" value="@string.Format("Add_{0}", Model.Groups[g].RowGroups[rg].RowGroupId)" name="submit">Add</button>
            }
        }
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
    }
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what each value is being out-putted as?

Comment: You'll need to elaborate on the question quite a lot if you want an answer.

Comment: How is it possible that you didn't bother to include any actually relevant information?  How is it possible that you expect an answer from such a vague question?  How is it possible I'm bothering to even write this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More importantly, are you sure this is an EditorTemplate problem?  If you put the code in your main view, does it also happen?  Did you try that?  Or did you assume it was an EditorTemplate problem?

Since you neglected to provide any context for your question, all we can do is guess.  More than likely, you have modified the contents of the view model in a post operation, and are now surprised that the Html helpers are using the old value rather than the value from the model.

If so, this is "by design", and a well documented (hundreds if not thousands of questions already here on SO about this issue).  The MVC Helpers prefer the contents of the ModelState over the model itself in post operations.  You have to clear the ModelState in order to work around it.

Comment: The 'ModalState.Clear()' did the job! Thanks.